# Crystal Report for Visual Studio 2022 (SP33) Version=13.0.4000.0 Error Reference when my previous application use with lower version

Tags: crystal-reports

I develop my previous app. in visual studio 2019 with Crystal report:CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0 and Later I have installed Visual Studio 2022 with new version Crystal Report SP33 :CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.4000.0  and I got this Error after run my Win Form Application :
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1705  Assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportSource' with identity 'CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'
uses 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' which has a higher version than referenced assembly
'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine' with identity 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'
I tried to find solutions but there is no fixed solution. I have uninstall CrystalReports and Reinstal them again but its error would be the same. Anyone has any suggestions?

I Carefully read the Error again that I reference the previous version of Crystal Report Version=13.0.2000.0 so First, I deleted all reference about Crystal Report as in the picture
[Delete all reference about Crystal Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBAPz.jpg)

Then I reinstall new Crystal Report SP33 CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.4000.0

I add new reference for all reference about Crystal Report again as in the picture: I selected them all

Add new reference for Crystal Report

[image: 1]

Then Error as I post disappeared.  So I hope that solutions in my case could help others.